# Freemarker URLTemplate loader adding internationalization to the template name and multiple loaders not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a Spring MVC application and I am trying to get freemarker as the view resolver. I am trying to get it set up so that it checks a different server first then locally.  Here is the relevant code:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
  <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/"/>
  <property name="preTemplateLoaders" ref="myTemplateLoader"/>
</bean>

<bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
        <property name="order" value="2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myTemplateLoader" class="com.xxx.MyURLTemplateLoader">
        <property name="baseUrl" value="http://10.0.0.5:8080/ftl/"/>
    </bean>
```

The class looks like this:

```
public class MyURLTemplateLoader extends URLTemplateLoader  {

private String baseUrl;

@Override
protected URL getURL(String arg0){
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(baseUrl+arg0);
        System.out.println("URL Being used:"+url.toString());
    } catch (Exception s) {
        s.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}

public String getBaseUrl() {
    return baseUrl;
}

public void setBaseUrl(String baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
}
```

}

the controller is this simple:

```
ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("index2");
return view;
```

Now when I run this I get a 404 error.  the weird thing is that I get this in the logs:

```
URL Being used:http://10.0.0.5:8080/ftl/index2_en_US.ftl
```

So why is that "_en_US"  being added to my URL?

Also,  if I remove the preTemplateLoaders,  it works fine, it picks up the local template just fine.  but adding the URLTemplateLoader,  not only does it add the _en_US to the template name, but it also fails to find it locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FreeMarker has a few unlucky legacy configuration defaults, one of them is that `localized_lookup` is by default `true`. That's why it first tries to find `index2_en_US.ftl`, then if that's missing `index2_en.ftl`, finally `index2.ftl`. Plus apparently the `TemplateLoader` implementation you are using has a incorrect `findTemplateSource` method, and thus the above fallback mechanism doesn't work. So, `findTemplateSource` should be fixed, and also you want to turn off localized lookup:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
  ...
  <property name="freemarkerSettings">
    <props>
      <prop key="localized_lookup">false</prop>
      <!-- Some unrelated but useful default overrides: -->
      <prop key="incompatible_improvements">2.3.23</prop>
      <prop key="template_exception_handler">rethrow</prop>
      <prop key="log_template_exceptions">false</prop>
      <prop key="default_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to ddekany for the localization problem.  That fixed it right up

The second problem however, was much harder.

It turns out there is an "undocumented feature" that if you set a template loader it wipes out the default loader (org.springframework.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader) so if you want 2 (or more) loaders, you need to roll your own. Unfortunately, SpringTemplateLoader takes a ServletContext as a construction argument, you can't (easily) define it in a context.xml file.

So what I did was re-write SpringTemplateLoader a bit to make it ServletContext aware. Here is my code:

```
public class MyWebappTemplateLoader implements TemplateLoader, ServletContextAware  {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyWebappTemplateLoader.class);
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader = null;
private String templateLoaderPath = null;
private ServletContext servletContext;

private void init() {
    GenericWebApplicationContext context = new  GenericWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    resourceLoader = (ResourceLoader)context;
    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info("SpringTemplateLoader for FreeMarker: using resource loader [" + this.resourceLoader +
                "] and template loader path [" + this.templateLoaderPath + "]");
    }       
}

public Object findTemplateSource(String name) throws IOException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Looking for FreeMarker template with name [" + name + "]");
    }
    if(this.resourceLoader==null) {
        init();
    }
    Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(this.templateLoaderPath + name);
    return (resource.exists() ? resource : null);
}


public Reader getReader(Object templateSource, String encoding) throws IOException {
    Resource resource = (Resource) templateSource;
    try {
        return new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), encoding);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Could not find FreeMarker template: " + resource);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}

public long getLastModified(Object templateSource) {
    return -1;
}

public void closeTemplateSource(Object templateSource) throws IOException {
}

public void setTemplateLoaderPath(String arg0) {
    if (!arg0.endsWith("/")) {
        arg0 += "/";
    }
    this.templateLoaderPath = arg0;
}

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext arg0) {
    this.servletContext = arg0;

}
}
```

and my xml now looks like this:

```
        <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="preTemplateLoaders" ref="multiTemplateLoader"/>  
        <property name="freemarkerSettings">
            <props>
                <prop key="default_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="localized_lookup">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>  
    </bean>


    <bean id="fremarkerViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
        <property name="order" value="2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUrlTemplateLoader" class="com.xxx.MyURLTemplateLoader">
        <property name="baseUrl" value="http://10.0.0.5:8080/ftl/"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultTemplateLoader" class="com.xxx.MyWebappTemplateLoader">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="multiTemplateLoader" class="freemarker.cache.MultiTemplateLoader">
        <constructor-arg>
          <list>
            <ref bean="myUrlTemplateLoader"/>
            <ref bean="defaultTemplateLoader"/> 
          </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

And one last thing.  The URLTemplateLoader MUST return a NULL if you want the loader to go to the next loader.  so I had to add this to my URLTemplateLoader:

```
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        if(conn.getResponseCode()!=200) {
            return null;
        }
```

If anyone knows of a better way, I would love to see it!